# Как организовать погрузку данных с помощью redux при загрузке страницы?

Tags: reactjs, redux

В свое время работал без `flux` и `redux` и данные хранил в `state` приложения, с помощью `setState` менял их. Сейчас решил освоиться в `redux`'е, организовал экшн и редьсер для дропдауна. Итемы дропдауна я буду формировать на основе ответа по апи(запрос делается в экшне, а редьюссер устанавлвиает приходящие данные  в пропсы). В `state` приложении для дропдаунов я делал запрос в `componentDidMount` и формировался дропдаун. Как лучше это сделать в `redux`?

Comment: в экшен-криэйторах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно так же в `componentDidMount` вызываете экшн который перехватываете в `middleware` и в зависимости от того выполнился ваш запрос или нет диспатчить другие экшены.

`redux-thunk` - один из популярных `middleware` для асинхронных экшенов.

```
const signIn = credentials => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.signIn(credentials);

    dispatch(authSuccess({ accessToken: 'myCollAccessToken' }));
    dispatch(push('/'));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(authFailure(error));
  }
};
```

Подробнее https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators